# How do you build an executable from haskell packages (which use stack / cabal) in nix?

Tags: haskell, nix, nixpkgs

I'm looking for something similar to this:

`shell.nix`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  threadscope = ...
  speedscope = ...
in
  stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "haskell-env";
    nativeBuildInputs = [
      # Haskell tools
      ghcid ghc

      # Profiling tools
      threadscope
      speedscope
    ];
  }
```

Then I can use `nix-shell`:

```
% nix-shell
...
nix-shell % threadscope <some-commands>
nix-shell % speedscope <some-commands>
```

Do you usually just build from source from github / hackage / stackage or use `pkgs.haskellPackages.<my-package>`?

Comment: I've changed your example to use `nativeBuildInputs` which is more suitable for shell tools. `buildInputs` is intended for libraries and such, but includes legacy behavior that is sub-optimal. For example, shell tab completion won't be supported for `buildInputs`. You'll see many examples that use `buildInputs` though, because it kind of works and it's a somewhat recent change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually take tools from `haskellPackages`.

If you only want a shell with tools, you can use an expression like this.

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

let
  # Select a package set. haskellPackages is recommended, but
  # if you need a different ghc, use pkgs.haskell.packages.ghc8102 for example
  haskellPackages = pkgs.haskellPackages;

in
  pkgs.mkShell {
    nativeBuildInputs = [
      # Haskell tools
      haskellPackages.ghc
      haskellPackages.ghcid

      # Profiling tools
      haskellPackages.threadscope
      # pkgs.speedscope (not packaged yet)
    ];
  }
```

If you want a shell with specific precompiled libraries, you can use the `ghcWithPackages` function instead of `ghc`. If you want precompiled dependencies for your local Haskell package(s), you can replace `pkgs.mkShell` by [the `haskellPackages.shellFor` function](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/2f26107b808791e358f0af59f25b016376e08216/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix#L282).

If you'd like to package speedscope, the Nixpkgs manual documents [the packaging process for node packages](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#node.js)